# jquery validate custom validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("insz", function (value, element) {
        var insz = $('#txtINSZ').val()
        var controle = parseInt(insz.substring(13, 15))
        var getal = insz.substring(0, 2) + insz.substring(3, 5) + insz.substring(6, 8) + insz.substring(9, 12)
        var rest = parseInt(getal) % 97
        alert("we doin' this mun")
        return 97 - rest == controle;
    }, "* Amount must be greater than zero");
    $('#form1').validate({
        rules: {
        
            txtINSZ: {
                required: $('#cbInsz').prop('checked') == false,
                insz: function () {
                    $('#cbInsz').prop('checked') == true;
                }
                }
        },
 

        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            this.defaultShowErrors();// to display the default error placement
         
                 
        }
        
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="#" id="form1" a="" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div id="container">
           
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-horizontal col-xs-4" id="divDimLeft">


            <span id="lblTitleAlgemeen">Algemen Informatie</span>
            <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:20px;">
                <span id="lblCheck">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="cbInsz" checked="">
                    INSZ nummer werknemer gekend?
       
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="divINSZ">

                <span id="lblINSZ" class="required" for="txtINSZ" aria-required="true">INSZ-nummer gekend?</span>
                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtINSZ" type="text" maxlength="15" id="txtINSZ" class="form-control required form valid" oninput="autoInvullen()" aria-required="true" placeholder="__.__.__-___.__" aria-invalid="false" required=""><label id="txtINSZ-error" class="error" for="txtINSZ" style="display: none;"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span id="lblNaam" class="required" for="txtNaam" aria-required="true">Naam</span>
                <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtNaam" type="text" maxlength="40" id="txtNaam" class="form-control form requiredField error" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true"><label id="txtNaam-error" class="error" for="txtNaam">Dit veld is verplicht.</label>
          
        </div>
        <div id="divButton" class="text-right" style="width: 87.5%">
            
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit" value="Volgende" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-2" style="float: none; min-width:200px;">

        </div>
  </div>
        </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>
</form>
```

I wanted to make a custom validator but for some reason it's not working at all. The required does work so there is no issue with finding the elements in my page. So is there someone who has any idea why it is not working?

Thans in advance, under here you find the code i'm using including the method I wrote and the start of the validate method.

Comment: You should also show the relevant HTML markup so a demo could be constructed.

Comment: did as you asked :)

Comment: Thanks but we need the ***rendered*** HTML markup as seen in the browser DOM, since that's what the JavaScript is actually using.

Comment: I also see that you're using ASP... does this also mean you're using the Unobtrusive Validation plugin?  If so, your call to `.validate()` will always be ignored.

Comment: @Sparky how can I show the html rendered (sorry new to stackover) and no I'm using the one from JQuery: https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: The rendered HTML can be found by inspecting the DOM via any browser.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with the code in your custom method.  Since validation fires on every keyup, you are evaluating the custom rule even when the field is incomplete.  Since you never described what this custom rule is supposed to do, it's impossible to know what needs to be done to fix it.

Comment: I'm sorry let me explain this. When the checkbox is checked it should run the custom validation which checks if the code is okay. If the code is not okay it would show an error message. The code is to check the passport number of people who have a passport in Belgium. The first 9 numbers need to be placed together and then you have to divide it by 97. This number should be equal to 97 minus the rest of the divide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I just putted the rules out of the rules section. After the validation code I putted this:

```
 $('#txtINSZ').rules("add", {
    required:true,
insz:true
})
```

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just insert a comparison operator all by itself as the parameter;  you need a `function` that returns the value of this parameter, in this case a boolean from the comparison operator...

```
$('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
        txtINSZ: {
            required: function() {
                return $('#cbInsz').prop('checked') == false;
            },
            insz: function() {
                return $('#cbInsz').prop('checked') == false;
            }
            ....
```

Comment: I just changed the code but the result is still the same. So that doesn't seem to be the issue since required works perfectly...

Comment: @Squarkz, `required` is only working because you also have `class="required"` on the input element. Remove the required rule from `.validate()` and see for yourself.   Without the `function`, this will not be dynamic, so toggling the checkbox will have no effect.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, the required works perfectly like I mentioned in the main post. Even without the classes on the input field.

Comment: @Squarkz, I think you misunderstand when I say your code is not dynamic.  If the `required` rule depends on the state of a checkbox, and should toggle this requirement along with the checkbox, then you must put it inside of a function.

Comment: yes it seems I misunderstood you. But that doesn't change the fact that my own method that I'm adding doesn't work.

Comment: @Squarkz, construct a jsFiddle demo and/or post your rendered HTML from the DOM so we have more to work with here.

Comment: @Squarkz, your script includes for the plugin is bungled up.  You cannot simply put a URL in quotes between tags; `<script>"URL"</script>` .  Include the plugin same way you include jQuery; <script src="URL"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same situation, but in my case below two steps worked.

1. use `data-rule-insz="true"` attribute on your HTML input element for which you want custom validation.
2. also add a `name` attribute as mentioned in the below example:-

   ```
   <input id="customer" name="customer" data-rule-insz="true" required type="text" class="typeahead form-control" />
   ```